# Pointer and Function ambiguity in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

Please look at the following code:

```
char* test ( )
{
    char word[20];
    printf ("Type a word: ");
    scanf ("%s", word);
    return word;
}

void main()
{
    printf("%s",test());
}
```

When the function returns, the variable `word` is destroyed and it prints some garbage value. But when I replace

```
char word[20];
```

by `char *word;`

it prints the correct value. According to me, the pointer variable should have been destroyed similar to the character array and the output should be some garbage value. Can anyone please explain the ambiguity?

Comment: Using `char *` here will result in **undefined behaviour**, because you didn't allocate any storage.

Comment: but its giving the correct answer!!!

Comment: "Undefined behaviour" does not mean "will crash" or "will give unexpected results"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Undefined behavior is just that - undefined. Sometimes it will appear to work, but that is just coincidence. In this case, it's possible that the uninitialized pointer just happens to point to valid writeable memory, and that memory is not used for anything else, so it successfully wrote and read the value. This is obviously not something you should count on.

Answer (score 2):

You have undefined behavior either way, but purely from a "what's going on here" viewpoint, there's still some difference between the two.

When you use an array, the data it holds is allocated on the stack. When the function returns, that memory will no longer be part of the stack, and almost certainly *will* be overwritten in the process of calling `printf`.

When you use the pointer, your data is going to be written to whatever random location that pointer happens to have pointed at. Though writing there is undefined behavior, simple statistics says that if you have (for example) a 32-bit address space of ~4 billion locations, the chances of hitting one that will be overwritten in the new few instructions is *fairly* low.

You obviously shouldn't do either one, *but* the result you got isn't particularly surprising either.

Comment: but still I am getting the correct result when using a pointer without allocating the memory

Comment: @AndroidDecoded: Once you write something to memory (assuming you do so successfully) it will stay there until power is removed, or something overwrites it. By pure bad luck, you just happen to have hit a location that didn't get overwritten by the next few instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Because the char array is defined and declared in the function, it is a local variable and no longer exists after the function returns. If you use a char pointer and *ALLOCATE MEMORY FOR IT* then it will remain, and all you need is the pointer (aka a number).

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("%s", test());
    return 0;
}

char* test(void) {
    char* str = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%19s", str);
    return str;
}
```

Notice how I used %19s instead of %s. Your current function can easily lead to a buffer overflow if a user enters 20 or more characters.

Answer (score 0):

During program execution first it will create activation records for the function `main` in stack segment of the process memory. In that `main` activation records it will allocate memory for the local variable of that function(`main`) and some more memory for internal purpose. In your program `main` doesn't has any local variable, so it will not allocate any memory for local variables in `main` activation records.

Then while executing the statement for calling the function `test`, it will create one more activation records for the calling function(`test`) and it will allocate `20` bytes for the local variable `word`.

Once the control exits the function `test`, activation record created for that function will be poped out of that stack. Then it will continue to execute the remaining statment (`printf`) of the called function `main`. Here printf is trying to print the characters in the `test` function's local variable which is already poped out of the stack. So this behaviour is undefined, sometimes it may print the proper string or else it will print some junk strings.

So in this situation only dynamic memory comes into picture. With the help of dynamic memory we can control the lifetime(or scope) of a variable. So use dynamic memory like below.

```
char *word = NULL:
word = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
```

Note : Take care of NULL check for the malloc return value and also dont forget to free the allocated memory after `printf` in main function.